# nodejs aws lambda ffmpeg command failure

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, ffmpeg, aws-lambda-layers

Im running an ffmpeg command to generate a thumbnail from a video that exists on aws s3 bucket but accessed from cloud front. So i try to stream the video in the command. This is implemented in nodejs and the ffmpeg dependency is a lambda layer. The code looks like so

```
const gifName = `${baseFilename}.gif`;
await execPromise(`ffmpeg -t 10 -ss 00:00:01 -i "${_url}" ${'/tmp/' + gifName}`);
```

`_url` is a clound front url. This works when i test locally even via aws SAM cli.
But this fails when testing the deployed fuction. The error output I get is as follows

```
2022-06-13T14:07:41.079Z    35af32d2-c63f-4942-abce-3ae7dad2a6c3    INFO    stderr:  ffmpeg version 5.0.1-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
  libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
  libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
  libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
  libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
  libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
  libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://d17yrtgi5800rj.cloudfront.net/staging/videos/a66a92eb-bc31-4440-958c-07ee23e55bcb':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2022-05-03T19:50:01.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 4.732124
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +52.3832+004.9205+018.038/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 13 Pro Max
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 15.4.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2022-05-03T21:50:01+0200
  Duration: 00:00:42.67, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 8434 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/arib-std-b67), 1920x1080, 8214 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-05-03T19:50:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : HEVC
    Side data:
      DOVI configuration record: version: 1.0, profile: 8, level: 4, rpu flag: 1, el flag: 0, bl flag: 1, compatibility id: 4
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 162 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-05-03T19:50:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-05-03T19:50:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:3[0x4](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 5 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-05-03T19:50:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:4[0x5](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 36 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-05-03T19:50:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> gif (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[hevc @ 0x63641c0] Multiple Dolby Vision RPUs found in one AU. Skipping previous.
[hevc @ 0x6375900] Multiple Dolby Vision RPUs found in one AU. Skipping previous.
[hevc @ 0x6333600] Multiple Dolby Vision RPUs found in one AU. Skipping previous.
Output #0, gif, to '/tmp/a66a92eb-bc31-4440-958c-07ee23e55bcb.gif':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2022-05-03T21:50:01+0200
    com.apple.quicktime.location.accuracy.horizontal: 4.732124
    com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709: +52.3832+004.9205+018.038/
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 13 Pro Max
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 15.4.1
    encoder         : Lavf59.16.100
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: gif, bgr8(pc, gbr/bt2020/arib-std-b67, progressive), 1080x1920, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 100 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-05-03T19:50:01.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.18.100 gif
    Side data:
      DOVI configuration record: version: 1.0, profile: 8, level: 4, rpu flag: 1, el flag: 0, bl flag: 1, compatibility id: 4
      displaymatrix: rotation of -0.00 degrees
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.325x    
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:00.18 bitrate=34952.5kbits/s speed=0.239x    
frame=    9 fps=6.6 q=-0.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:00.34 bitrate=55512.8kbits/s speed=0.248x    
frame=   14 fps=7.0 q=-0.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:00.51 bitrate=57568.9kbits/s speed=0.255x    
frame=   19 fps=7.2 q=-0.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:00.68 bitrate=61680.9kbits/s speed=0.259x    
frame=   24 fps=7.4 q=-0.0 size=    6656kB time=00:00:00.84 bitrate=64911.8kbits/s speed=0.258x    
frame=   29 fps=7.5 q=-0.0 size=    7936kB time=00:00:01.01 bitrate=64368.0kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   33 fps=7.5 q=-0.0 size=    9472kB time=00:00:01.14 bitrate=68065.5kbits/s speed=0.259x    
frame=   37 fps=7.5 q=-0.0 size=   10752kB time=00:00:01.28 bitrate=68812.8kbits/s speed=0.261x    
frame=   42 fps=7.6 q=-0.0 size=   12032kB time=00:00:01.44 bitrate=68448.7kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   46 fps=7.6 q=-0.0 size=   13312kB time=00:00:01.58 bitrate=69020.2kbits/s speed=0.261x    
frame=   50 fps=7.6 q=-0.0 size=   14336kB time=00:00:01.71 bitrate=68678.7kbits/s speed=0.261x    
frame=   54 fps=7.6 q=-0.0 size=   15360kB time=00:00:01.84 bitrate=68385.4kbits/s speed=0.259x    
frame=   58 fps=7.6 q=-0.0 size=   16640kB time=00:00:01.98 bitrate=68845.9kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   62 fps=7.6 q=-0.0 size=   17664kB time=00:00:02.11 bitrate=68579.9kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   66 fps=7.6 q=-0.0 size=   18944kB time=00:00:02.24 bitrate=69280.9kbits/s speed=0.259x    
frame=   70 fps=7.6 q=-0.0 size=   20224kB time=00:00:02.38 bitrate=69611.3kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   74 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   21504kB time=00:00:02.51 bitrate=70183.6kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   78 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   22784kB time=00:00:02.64 bitrate=70699.4kbits/s speed=0.259x    
frame=   82 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   24064kB time=00:00:02.78 bitrate=70910.9kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   86 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   25600kB time=00:00:02.91 bitrate=72067.1kbits/s speed=0.259x    
frame=   91 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   27136kB time=00:00:03.08 bitrate=72174.7kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   95 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   28416kB time=00:00:03.21 bitrate=72518.3kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=   99 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   29696kB time=00:00:03.34 bitrate=72835.2kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  103 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   30976kB time=00:00:03.48 bitrate=72918.2kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  108 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   32768kB time=00:00:03.64 bitrate=73746.0kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  112 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   34048kB time=00:00:03.78 bitrate=73788.7kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  116 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   35072kB time=00:00:03.91 bitrate=73480.8kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  120 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   36352kB time=00:00:04.04 bitrate=73711.8kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  124 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   37376kB time=00:00:04.18 bitrate=73249.8kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  128 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   38656kB time=00:00:04.31 bitrate=73473.3kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  132 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   39936kB time=00:00:04.44 bitrate=73683.7kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  136 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   41216kB time=00:00:04.58 bitrate=73720.8kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  141 fps=7.7 q=-0.0 size=   42496kB time=00:00:04.74 bitrate=73444.6kbits/s speed=0.26x    
frame=  145 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   43776kB time=00:00:04.88 bitrate=73486.3kbits/s speed=0.261x    
frame=  150 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   45312kB time=00:00:05.04 bitrate=73650.0kbits/s speed=0.261x    
frame=  154 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   46336kB time=00:00:05.18 bitrate=73278.9kbits/s speed=0.261x    
frame=  159 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   47616kB time=00:00:05.34 bitrate=73046.9kbits/s speed=0.261x    
frame=  164 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   49152kB time=00:00:05.51 bitrate=73076.8kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  168 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   50176kB time=00:00:05.64 bitrate=72879.8kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  173 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   51456kB time=00:00:05.81 bitrate=72552.1kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  178 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   52736kB time=00:00:05.98 bitrate=72243.0kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  183 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   54272kB time=00:00:06.14 bitrate=72409.8kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  187 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   55552kB time=00:00:06.28 bitrate=72465.3kbits/s speed=0.263x    
frame=  191 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   56832kB time=00:00:06.41 bitrate=72631.5kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  196 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   58368kB time=00:00:06.58 bitrate=72667.3kbits/s speed=0.263x    
frame=  200 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   59648kB time=00:00:06.71 bitrate=72822.1kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  204 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   60928kB time=00:00:06.84 bitrate=72971.1kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  208 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   62208kB time=00:00:06.98 bitrate=73009.7kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  212 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   63488kB time=00:00:07.11 bitrate=73149.6kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  216 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   64768kB time=00:00:07.24 bitrate=73284.5kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  220 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   66048kB time=00:00:07.38 bitrate=73315.1kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  224 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   67072kB time=00:00:07.51 bitrate=73163.0kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  228 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   68352kB time=00:00:07.64 bitrate=73290.5kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  232 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   69632kB time=00:00:07.78 bitrate=73319.5kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  236 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   70912kB time=00:00:07.91 bitrate=73440.1kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  240 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   72192kB time=00:00:08.04 bitrate=73556.8kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  245 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   73728kB time=00:00:08.21 bitrate=73566.4kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  249 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   75008kB time=00:00:08.34 bitrate=73676.9kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  253 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   76288kB time=00:00:08.48 bitrate=73697.1kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  257 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   77568kB time=00:00:08.61 bitrate=73802.2kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  261 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   78848kB time=00:00:08.74 bitrate=73904.2kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  265 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   80128kB time=00:00:08.88 bitrate=73919.9kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  269 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   81152kB time=00:00:09.01 bitrate=73784.4kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  273 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   82432kB time=00:00:09.14 bitrate=73882.2kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  278 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   83712kB time=00:00:09.31 bitrate=73659.4kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  282 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   84992kB time=00:00:09.44 bitrate=73755.8kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  287 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   86784kB time=00:00:09.61 bitrate=73978.6kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  291 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   88064kB time=00:00:09.74 bitrate=74067.8kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  295 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   89344kB time=00:00:09.88 bitrate=74079.6kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  299 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 size=   90624kB time=00:00:10.01 bitrate=74165.0kbits/s speed=0.262x    
frame=  300 fps=7.8 q=-0.0 Lsize=   91358kB time=00:00:10.04 bitrate=74542.5kbits/s speed=0.261x    
video:91358kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000021%
```

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can access the input, so that looks correct.

How long does it run for?

Does it time out?

Comment: it does not timeout, runs for a few seconds max 10 seconds

Comment: does it hit a memory limit?

Comment: it does not i tested those again, does not run out of memory or disk space